# Bootstrap File Upload + Django Form

Tags: django, image, forms, twitter-bootstrap, field

Hi I'm trying to customize my django form and add the [file upload widget from Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#imageupload). However, it doesn't seem to be working..

```
 <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
   <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /></div>
   <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
 <div>
 <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">{{ wizard.form.main_image }}</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
   <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Have I put `{{ wizard.form.main_image }}` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
   <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /></div>
   <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
 <div>
 <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select an Image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
   {{ wizard.form.main_image }}</span>
   <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
   </div>
</div>
```